# 502 as response in preflight request

Tags: javascript, axios

I've been using `axios` for a while but yesterday it started to catch `502` on some (not all) preflight (OPTIONS) responses.

My config is pretty default

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'my.api.url',
    transformResponse: myTransformFunction,
});
```

Any ideas why it is coming out right now, and why is it like this on just some responses?

Answer (score 2):

As Michal stated, 502 means Bad Gateway. When you see this on a preflight request that usually means that there is a problem with your Options headers. Since you've stated that you're seeing this in production, but not in development, that indicates to me that your headers are valid for your development domain, but not for your production domain.

To fix this the you would need to ensure that the API's server is responding with

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

OR

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.myProductionDomain.com

Outside of that, since it sound like you don't have access to change those properties, you could ensure that your production version is using the same domain as your development version.

Comment: We have the correct domain set, but some of those request go through like nothing, and some (like 10 out of 100) are stopped and I get 502

Answer (score 1):

502 is a server error. This means that there's a problem with the API and not with your request.

Comment: Weird, as the backend says they did not change anything when it comes to the code. It happens only in production, and no such problem when working locally

Comment: Perhaps you need to use another API key for Production?

Comment: Or different hostname?

Comment: @Jon No, the OP said that it only happens with some responses. There is definitely a problem with the backend.

Comment: Any idea guys how to debug it from the API perspective?

Comment: Checking, nothing there. I found an article that it might be an overreactive DDOS protection system of the server that we are using